# Pourquoi le gentilé « Saoudien(ne) » n'est pas « Arabo-Saoudien(ne) » ?

Tags: origine-ou-raison, toponymes, mots-composés, gentilés

En lisant un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/asie-oceanie/201901/06/01-5210124-une-saoudienne-demandeuse-dasile-en-instance-dexpulsion-de-bangkok.php) concernant une *Saoudienne*, je me pose la question du [gentilé](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1941) (d'[Arabie saoudite](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabie_saoudite)).

- Pourquoi le gentilé se compose-t-il uniquement du deuxième élément du
  nom du pays (pourquoi n'est-ce pas *Arabo-Saoudien(ne)*, le préfixe [existe](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/arabo-islamique/4905?q=arabo#4881)); est-ce basé
  sur la version courte du [toponyme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabie_saoudite#Toponymie) de langue arabe (qui si je comprends bien réfère au nom de la famille royale alors qu'à l'évidence les habitants du pays ne descendent pas tous de cette famille) ?
- En parcourant rapidement une [liste](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=1&Th_id=143) de gentilés, je constate que
  quand un nom comporte un élément associé à un point cardinal on a les
  deux termes avec au moins un pays (Sud-Africain(e) pour [Afrique du
  Sud](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1941)) ; y a-t-il d'autres noms composés de pays dont aucun terme
  ne correspond à un point cardinal et dont le gentilé est formé
  comme celui du pays en question ?

Comment: On utilise souvent le 2eme mot de nom du pays (tchèque, congolais) sauf s'il peux porter à confusion (africain / sud africain). Pour d'autre pays comme la république de Corée on dit souvent seulement coréen sauf si il faut préciser. Il n'y pas, je pense de règles établies.

Comment: Pour l'arabie Saoudite, il y a peut-etre aussi le fait que Souad est la famille qui a le pays. Combien de Saoudiens (i.e. citoyens, ils ne sont pas si nombreux...) ne sont pas de la famille Saoud?

Comment: De même que les habitants de Grande Bretagne sont appelés « Britanniques » et non pas « Grands Bretons »

Comment: @Toto Merci, je comprends votre point, mais on n'appelle pas les habitants de la Grande-Bretagne les _Lancastériens_ pour autant....

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda Merci, n'hésitez pas à verser votre commentaire en réponse !

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Merci, aucune idée, la population a près de 30 millions. J'ai lu qu'en 1932 la famille en question a reconquis le pays. Ça impliquerait que les habitants n'en sont pas tous des descendants. Mais je ne me prononce pas là-dessus, mes connaissances sont plus que sommaires.

Answer (score 2):

On a, par exemple :

[Sao Tomé-et-Principe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sao_Tom%C3%A9-et-Principe) --> Santoméen

[Bosnie-Herzégovine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosnie-Herz%C3%A9govine)  --> Bosnien

[Papouasie-Nouvelle-Guinée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papouasie-Nouvelle-Guin%C3%A9e)  -->  Papouasien

Answer (score 2):

On utilise souvent le 2eme mot de nom du pays (tchèque, congolais) sauf s'il peut porter à confusion (africain / sud africain). Pour d'autres pays comme la république de Corée on dit souvent seulement coréen sauf si il faut préciser. Il n'y pas, je pense de règles établies.

Voici quelques liens pour compléter mes propos qui ne sont que du ressentis.

[Liste Des Gentilés des pays](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_gentil%C3%A9s)

[Comment dériver un gentilé à partir d'un toponyme ?](https://www.cairn.info/revue-cahiers-de-sociolinguistique-2006-1-page-63.htm)