# D'où vient le suffixe -ite et que signifie-t-il ?

Tags: étymologie, suffixes

Il y a plusieurs mots finissant en -ite et je ne vois pas le point commun entre ceux-ci :

- limite
- chattemite
- sodomite
- pépite
- catamite
- antisémite (même si cela provient sûrement du mot sémite)
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour la plupart des mots ce préfixe n'a pas de signification particulière.

Dans le domaine médical, il désigne une inflammation

> Otite, sinusite, conjonctivite

Il désigne également des minéraux

> Pyrite, malachite, ophite, granite

Il semble aussi qu'il puisse être utilisé pour désigner un peuple ou une appartenance à un groupe religieux. Aucune certitude sur ce point-là cependant.

> malawite, sémite, hittite, jésuite, jacobite, israélite, saoudite, sodomite (initialement "habitants de Sodom")

Dans ce cas-là et comme pour [de nombreux](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33315/pourquoi-le-gentil%c3%a9-saoudienne-nest-pas-arabo-saoudienne) noms [de peuples](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentil%c3%a9s) ou de langues, c'est plus un motif récurent qu'un suffixe ayant une signification précise.

Comment: « C'est plus un motif récurrent qu'un suffixe ayant une signification précise » : non. Ce suffixe est un héritage du grec qui l'utilisait déjà accolé à un nom propre (personne ou lieu) pour signifier  « qui appartient à », et ça a été repris en latin. Je ne vois pas beaucoup de noms de peuples ou de langues qui finissent par -ite, des exemples ?

Answer (score 2):

Si vous ne trouvez aucun point commun entre ces mots, c'est parce qu'il n'y en a effectivement aucun.

Le suffixe -ite existe mais il est utilisé pour signifier une inflammation (otite, bronchite, ...).

Ici c'est juste une coïncidence que tous ces mots finissent par -ite.

Voici un site répertoriant tous les affixes de la langue francaise (préfixes et suffixes) : http://www.aly-abbara.com/litterature/medicale/affixes/i.html

Comment: Ce n'est pas forcément une coïncidence, le suffixe -ite sert à désigner les membres d'un groupe comme sémite (Sem + ite), sodomite (Sodome +ite), etc...

Answer (score 1):

Ce suffixe est expliqué comme suit dans le TLFi;

> Suff. reproduisant le lat. -ita et servant à former des subst. désignant le plus souvent le partisan d'une pers. ou d'une doctrine. V. adamite, ammonite, barnabite, carmélite, ismaélite, jésuite, moabite, maronite, sémite, sodomite, sunnite.

Dans « chattemite » « ite » n'est pas le suffixe mais la terminaison de « mite » ( Petit arthropode notamment arachnide ou acarien).

Dans « limite » il ne s'agit pas du suffixe non plus mais du mot latin « itis »

Dans « pépite » on ne trouve pas le suffixe non plus parce que ce mot vient de l'espagnol.

Dans ses notes pour Le Plaidoyer pour C. Cornelius, de Cicéron, M. de Golbery indique en 1834 : « Le mot catamite a sans doute donné lieu à notre vieux mot chattemite, qui se trouve employé dans La Fontaine ». C'est un mot qui provient du latin « catamitus » : nom ancien de Ganymède; homme débauché, mignon.

Pour trouver un suffixe comme « ite » dans le TLFi, taper simplement « -ite » ou « ite ».